# Make element move when hover over an element within parent element but not when on the other child

Tags: html, css

I have this div

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-6 row director-inner mx-auto py-3">
   <div class="director-info row" onclick="void(0)">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-6 offset-3 offset-md-0">
         <img src="../junior/images/GS.png"  alt="" class="py-2 profile-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 d-flex flex-column flex-md-row flex-wrap align-content-center text-center text-md-left">
         <h3>First Last</h3>
         <p><a href="tel:7327301000">732-730-1000</a> x635<br>
            <a href="mailto:name@domain.org">name@domain.org</a><br>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i> @name<br>
            <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/name/">@name</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="profile p-4" onclick="void(0)">
      <h3 class="text-left profile-text">Name Last</h3>
      <p class="text-justify profile-text" >Name, an Israeli native, is our Junior TorahMates Coordinator who is in charge of setting up TorahMate partnerships, and makes sure everyone’s learning is going well. If you have any questions, Name's the one who can help! When she’s not at her desk (and sometimes when she is!), Name enjoys dancing, books, and pizza. </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

The .director-info div shows the whole time. Right now when you hover anywhere on the .director-info div, the .profile div slides in. The problem is that you can't click on any of the links in the former div because as soon as you hover anywhere in there, the .profile div covers it up.

So I want to make it that it only slides in when hovering over the img div, stays in, and as soon as you move the cursor off the image, it slides back out. How can I do this? Here is the css I have so far:

```
.director-container{
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
}
.director-inner, .profile{
background-color:white;
border-radius: 15px;

}
.director-inner{
overflow:hidden;
position: relative;
}
.director-inner a{
text-decoration: none;
color:inherit;
}
.profile{
left:100%;
position: absolute;
height:100%;
width:100%;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;

}

.director-inner:hover .profile{
left:0;

}

.director h2{
font-weight: bold;
color:#fff;
font-size: 50px;
letter-spacing: .5px;
line-height: 1;
}
.director h3{
color:#004990;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 30px;
padding-top:10px;
line-height: 1;
}
.director h3.profile-text{
font-size: 20px;
padding:0;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-top:-1.5rem;
}
p.profile-text{
font-size:15px;
line-height: 1.4;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You will need javascript to achieve this, given your current structure, it is not possible to do this with css only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can move the .profile to the same level as the img container div, this will work:

```css
.director-inner{
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
}
.director-inner, .profile{
background-color:white;
border-radius: 15px;
 border:solid 1px red;
}
.director-inner{
overflow:hidden;
position: relative;
}
.director-inner a{
text-decoration: none;
color:inherit;
}
.profile{
left:100%;
top:0;
position: absolute;
height:100%;
width:100%;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;

}

.director-info>div:first-child:hover ~ .profile{
left:0;
pointer-events:none;
}

.director h2{
font-weight: bold;
color:#fff;
font-size: 50px;
letter-spacing: .5px;
line-height: 1;
}
.director h3{
color:#004990;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 30px;
padding-top:10px;
line-height: 1;
}
.director h3.profile-text{
font-size: 20px;
padding:0;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-top:-1.5rem;
}
p.profile-text{
font-size:15px;
line-height: 1.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-6 row director-inner mx-auto py-3">
  <div class="director-info row" onclick="void(0)">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-6 offset-3 offset-md-0">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"  alt="" class="py-2 profile-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 d-flex flex-column flex-md-row flex-wrap align-content-center text-center text-md-left">
      <h3>First Last</h3>
      <p>
        <a href="tel:7327301000">732-730-1000</a> x635<br>
        <a href="mailto:name@domain.org">name@domain.org</a><br>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i> @name<br>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/name/">@name</a>
      </p>
    </div>
      <div class="profile p-4" onclick="void(0)">
    <h3 class="text-left profile-text">Name Last</h3>
    <p class="text-justify profile-text" >Name, an Israeli native, is our Junior TorahMates Coordinator who is in charge of setting up TorahMate partnerships, and makes sure everyone’s learning is going well. If you have any questions, Name's the one who can help! When she’s not at her desk (and sometimes when she is!), Name enjoys dancing, books, and pizza. </p>
  </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

With the current structure you cannot write the css selector you need

If you abslutely need to keep the structure, consider giving the links section a bigger z-index, on hover:

```css
.col-md-7:hover{
  z-index:3;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @TiagoCoelho! This worked! Sorry I didn't get to this sooner. My only question now is when I mouse off of the image area while the profile is open, into the information area, is there a way to have the profile slide out, being that I'm hovering over the profile and not the information which is underneath? I assume I can do this using javascript, but I really want to stick to css.

Comment: @Shifra I edited my code to do that. basically just added a pointer-events:none to profile to allow the underneath items drive the slide-in/out of profile.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's something I never knew before.